# Easy way to clean up the invalidated sessions from a Java Web Application's memory

Tags: java, session, servlets, garbage-collection, httpsession

I know `session.invalidate()` releases the httpsession. But when I monitor the container memory, it does not come down. Here is what I am observing -

- Login (My application creates a session)
- User performs some activity that increases the process memory.
- Logout. (Logout controller invalidates the session explicitly)
- Monitor the process memory. It never comes down.

Initially I thought, the garbage collection might work only after reaching a low memory available state. To confirm this, I used -Xmx to give less memory. But still the same error. Infact, I saw OOM error when I did the same activity with a separate browser.

Is there any thing missing here?

Comment: It may not actually be session data that's taking up heap space. Consider using "jmap -dump:file=/tmp/heap.hprof <pid>" to get a snapshot of the process heap, and then using a tool like Eclipse MAT to view the actual contents.

Comment: I tried this and was sure after the dump analysis that the data in the memory is the process that user did while she was logged in.

Comment: Eclipse MAT can also tell you which objects are responsible for keeping a specific object in memory. The "Dominator" reports can be great for this -- if there's a thread or object that still holds the data, you can use the dominator information to figure out what it is. I realize this isn't very specific but unless something is broken, the container shouldn't keep old session data around. Chances are there's another object holding a reference.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I used MAT to get the exact object that is taking huge memory. What I do is, I create this object and keep it in Session. (I have to for different reasons). Once the session is invalidated, I expect this object to go for garbage collection. But that never happens.

Comment: That's pretty strange. Maybe there's another reference to it? What if you use `httpSession.removeAttribute` before invalidating the session?

Answer (score 1):

It will be there in memory till garbage collector runs and finds the non referenced objects and cleans them up. You can try to explicitly call GC using `System.gc()` after `session.invalidate()` just for testing purpose. Also calling `System.gc()` need not invoke GC as jvm will do the decision whether to run GC or not.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that System.gc() can force a very expensive garbage-collection cycle, causing the JVM to become unresponsive for seconds or longer depending on total heap size. The system will use cheaper GC methods when appropriate, so an explicit System.gc() in response to user activity (such as session invalidation) is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Explicit System.gc will not be a real time option. I also explored "garbage-collection-interval" settings in the container. But various forums suggested not to decrease it too much for the same reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the following to analyze the problem:

1. Print GC logs and see if and how many Young/Full GC collections occur:

   > -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=jvm.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError    -Xloggc:bin/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -verbose:gc
2. Check Class Histograms to see if the instances of your class are being collected by Full GCs. Compare the number of instances before/after a Full GC. Enable :

   > -XX:+PrintClassHistogramBeforeFullGC -XX:+PrintClassHistogramAfterFullGC
3. Take histogram snapshots, again to see if the class is being collected:

   > jmap -histo $pid
4. See if the class contains a finalize() method that will prevent the object to be collected during a GC.
5. As GargantuChet suggested, collect the HeapDump and see which objects are referencing your class instances.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "Monitor the process memory"? The process memory used does not necessery equals to Heap occupation. The GC may have garbage-collected your instances, which has impact on Heap Usage, but may not be visible in the "process memory size" statistic.

Comment: Thanks for all the points mentioned above. I will definately check on them. But what you are saying the memory usage shown in Task Manager does not reflect the latest memory stats? From what I have seen, my application throws OOM exactly when the memory in task manager reaches to -Xmx memory.

Comment: I think you should check the GC logs to see what is exactly happening in the Heap. The stat showing the total memory reserved by your JVM does not necessarily need to reflect the Heap occupancy. The VM may for example reserve all the pages in advance. Also, use **-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError** to see which instances trigger OOM.